# Calling from back-end systems in MobileFirst V8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am migrating my MFP project from V7.1 to V8.0. Right now I am in process of migrating the java script adapter which I used to to validate username and password in MFP V7.1. This adapter calls a REST API which validate entered username and password in the enterprise server and, if authenticated successfully, brings back some data which I use in my app to decide subsequent flow.

I read the MFP V8.0 Authentication tutorial and was looking into [this](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/SecurityCheckAdapters/tree/release80/UserLogin) sample adapter. From what I understand there is always going to be one java class associated with security check which implement the `validateCredentials()` method in which we define how username/password are going to be validate.

My question is, how can I call my back-end REST Service from here? Is there any sample code available from where I can get the idea what needs to be done? Or do I have to write the java code inside the `validateCredentials()` method to get the desired results?

**--UPDATE--**

for example, consider below scenario:

```
    @Override
    protected boolean validateCredentials(Map<String, Object> credentials) {
        if(credentials!=null && credentials.containsKey("username") && credentials.containsKey("password")){
            String username = credentials.get("username").toString();
            String password = credentials.get("password").toString();

           //What should I write here so that I can validate the credential
           //on my enterprise server? Lets say, call the unprotected 
           //adapter method which will validate the credentials for me?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Resource Request tutorial teaches you how to call adapters, be it JavaScript adapters or Java adapters. See the tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/resource-request/javascript/

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    "/adapters/JavaAdapter/users",
    WLResourceRequest.GET
);
```

- For JavaScript adapters, use /adapters/{AdapterName}/{procedureName}
- For Java adapters, use /adapters/{AdapterName}/{path}. The path depends on how you defined your @Path annotations in your Java code. This would also include any @PathParam you used.
- To access resources outside of the project, use the full URL as per the requirements of the external server.

Comment: can you see my updated question, this should bring more clarity to what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to call an HTTP endpoint from within Java Adapter, these links should help:

1. [Java HTTP Adapter MFP 8.0](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/Adapters/blob/release80/JavaHTTP/src/main/java/com/sample/JavaHTTPResource.java)
2. [Java HTTP Adapter MFP 7.1](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/java-adapter/java-http-adapter/)